# Describe the cover relation for this partial order.

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:** Let $n$ be a set of positive integers and let $X_n$ be the set of all $n!$ permutations of $\{1,2,..,n\}.$ Let $\pi$ and $\sigma$ be two permutations in $X_n$ and define $\pi\leq \sigma$ provided that the set of inversions of $\pi$ is a subset of the set of inversions of $\sigma$. Verify that this defines a partial order on $X_n$ called the inversion poset. D**escribe the cover relation for this partial order** and then draw the diagram for the inversion poset $(H_4,\leq ).$

I am having trouble with the part in bold. I am guessing that the cover relation $<$ could be defined as follows $$\pi<\sigma\text{ iff the set of inversions of $\pi$ is a proper subset of the set of inversions of $\sigma$. }$$

However for $n=4$, consider the following three permutations $x_1=1324$, $x_2=3241$ and $x_3=4321$. The set of inversions for these permutations is $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,1,3\}$ and $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Now clearly for the choice of $x_1$ and $x_3$ it is possible to find $x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2<x_3.$ Thus violating the very definition of a cover. How do I go about defining a cover relation such that for any two permutations $x,z$, there does not exist another permutation $y$ such that $x<y<z$? Maybe I am wrong in interpreting the idea of a cover relation and if so please correct me otherwise any ideas regarding the problem mentioned in the bold part would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the cover relation is that the inversion set of $\pi$ is contained in that of $\sigma$ and has one fewer inversion. I also suspect that $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are linked by multiplying by a transposition $(i\ i+1)$ on the appropriate side.